# Using MAE as the error function for a linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'd like to perform linear regression, however instead of using RMSE as my error function, I'd like to use MAE (Mean Absolute Error).

Is there a package that would allow me to do this?

Comment: `quantreg` package does it - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/index.html

Comment: Traditionally mathematicians avoid optimizing on MAE because it isn't differentiable.  That doesn't mean it can't be done.  You can do it in base R with optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You may use *caret* and *Metrics* packages.

```
library(caret)
data("mtcars")
maeSummary <- function (data,
                        lev = NULL,
                        model = NULL) {

  require(Metrics)
  out <- mae(data$obs, data$pred)  
  names(out) <- "MAE"
  out
}

mControl <- trainControl(summaryFunction = maeSummary)

set.seed(123)
lm_model <- train(mpg ~ wt,
                  data = mtcars, 
                  method = "lm",
                  metric = "MAE",
                  maximize = FALSE,
                  trControl = mControl)
> lm_model$metric
[1] "MAE"
```

Comment: Sorry this answer is wrong... still optimized on RMSE (compare coefficients to confirm `lm_model` vs `lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars)$coefficients`

Answer (score 0):

Probably late to the party, but here is a solution using `CVXR` package for optimisation.

```
library(CVXR)

# defining variables to be tuned during optimisation
coefficient <- Variable(1)
intercept <- Variable(1)

# defining the objective i.e. minimizing the sum af absolute differences (MAE)
objective <- Minimize(sum(abs(mtcars$disp - (mtcars$hp * coefficient) - intercept)))

# optimisation
problem <- Problem(objective)
result <- solve(problem)

# result
result$status
mae_coefficient <- result$getValue(coefficient)
mae_intercept <- result$getValue(intercept)

lm_coeff_intrc <- lm(formula = disp ~ hp, data = mtcars)$coefficients

library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(
    slope = lm_coeff_intrc["hp"],
    intercept = lm_coeff_intrc["(Intercept)"],
    color = "red"
  ) +
  geom_abline(
    slope = mae_coefficient,
    intercept = mae_intercept,
    color = "blue"
  )

df <- mtcars %>%
  select(disp, hp) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(
    mae = disp - hp * mae_coefficient - mae_intercept,
    lm = disp - hp * lm_coeff_intrc["hp"] - lm_coeff_intrc["(Intercept)"]
  )

df %>%
  select(mae, lm) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:2) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(
    mae = sum(abs(value))
  )
```